# React useState setting initial state to null with large object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've been using hooks for a while and i thought i understood the basics, but since yesterday i have a bug in my code that makes me feel a little overwhelmed.
The code is simple i think:

```
const initialState = {
  userId: "",
  clientId: "",
  discount: "",
  paymentMethod: "CASH",
  medicalInurance: "",
  total: "",
  pending: "",
  detail: [
    {
      product: { 
        id: 1, 
        name: "u1v-13cs" 
      },
      unitPrice: 1500,
      totalPrice: 2400,
      discount: 20,
      quantity: 2
    }
  ],
  payments: {
    amount: 1000,
    invoice: "REGULAR",
    paymentMethod: "CASH"
  }
};

function sale = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState(initialState);
  return <FormSteps values={values} />
}
```

As you can see the code is pretty simple, but initial state is pretty large. And the bug is that state is set to null with that big object. 
If i simple delete some keys like that:

```
const initialState = {
  userId: "",
  clientId: "",
  discount: "",
  paymentMethod: "CASH",
  insurance: "",
  total: "",
  pending: ""
};
```

**it works as expected and initial state is well set.**

I know that i could simply split the initial state, but it make my logic different with other similar form components , so i firstly want to understand this behavior.

Comment: How do you populate that state after? are you pulling from a API feed or just setting it along the way?

Comment: With complex state likes that, I recommend you to use `useReducer` hook. Or split your big single state into smaller states.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error from `function sale = () => {`. But when I change to `function sale() {` it is initializing the whole object correctly as expected. My guess would be that your bug lies in the `FormSteps` component and is possibly mutating your original state object. Can you show us how it works?

Comment: You can reproduce yourself by replacing the `FormSteps` with an empty div, and console logging the state values before render.

Comment: is it the same if you capitalize `sale` into `Sale`?

Comment: `function Sale() { ... }` doesn't seem to have any bugs like one described in the question.